# How to retrieve data from firestore on react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I'm trying to retrieve data from my collection on firestore but when i put this data inside a component such as Text i get an error, however when a i put this same data on console.log() i can use its value with no problems.

**My code**

```
const nome = firestore().collections('usuários').doc(auth().currentUser.uid).get().then(
(documentSnapshot) => documentSnapshot.get('nome'))

return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                    <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
                        <Image source={require('../assets/img/user-bg.jpg')} style={styles.image} />
                    </View>


                    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                        <View style={styles.userLabel}>
                            <Text style={[styles.user, { color: colors.text }]}>{nome}</Text>
                            <Text style={[styles.email, { color: colors.text }]}>email</Text>
                        </View>

                        <CaretDownIcon width={8} height={8} fill={colors.text} style={{ marginRight: 10 }}/>
                    </View>
                </View>
    </View>
)
```

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get nome, you have:

```
const nome = firestore().collections('usuários').doc(auth().currentUser.uid).get().then(
(documentSnapshot) => documentSnapshot.get('nome'))
```

This doesn't return a name! Instead:
`firestore().collections('usuários').doc(auth().currentUser.uid).get()` returns a `Promise`. So what you want to happen is:

1. Fetch the name
2. Display the name

But what is happening instead is:

1. You ask firebase to fetch the name with `.get()`. `.get()` and `.then()` return a `Promise`, which is an `Object` (hence why you're getting that error)
2. Your page renders with the `Object`
3. Firebase finishes fetching the name and then calls the function in `name`, i.e.
   `(documentSnapshot) => documentSnapshot.get('nome')`

So instead, consider:

1. Change `<Text style={[styles.user, { color: colors.text }]}>{nome}</Text>`
   into `<Text style={[styles.user, { color: colors.text }]}>{this.state.nome}</Text>`
2. Change `(documentSnapshot) => documentSnapshot.get('nome')` to `(documentSnapshot) => {let _nome = documentSnapshot.get('nome'); this.setState({nome:_nome})`

And then what happens is that

1. You ask firebase to fetch the name
2. Your page renders, but firebase doesn't have your name yet. (it'll show up as undefined, but that's ok, because then:
3. Firebase fetches your name and then calls `setState`
4. React updates the page for you automatically with the new name when `setState` is called

If you don't want an `undefined` name, you can try something like `<Text>{this.state.nome || "Waiting for response..."}</Text>`.

If you're using an ES6 function renderer right now, you'll need to use a React Class instead.